# sbt cannot resolve plugin from local repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I do have my own plugin that I pulish local with 'publish-local'. Could resolve that plugin in other projects using previous versions of sbt, but it does not work any longer.

```
build.sbt of the plugin
sbtPlugin       := true

name            := "sumosim-webstart"

organization    := "net.entelijan"

version         := "1.3"

scalaVersion    := "2.10.0"

crossPaths      := false

publishTo       := Some("entelijan-repo" at "http://entelijan.net/artifactory/repositories/libs-ivy-local/")

credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "entelijan.net", "xxxx", "xxxx")

//scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked")
```

That is the output produced by sbt publish-local

```
 [exec] [info] Packaging /home/wolfi/prj/sumosim/sumosim-pom/sumosim-webstart/target/sbt-0.12/sumosim-webstart-1.3-javadoc.jar ...
 [exec] [info] Done packaging.
 [exec] [info]  published sumosim-webstart to /home/wolfi/.ivy2/local/net.entelijan/sumosim-webstart/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.3/poms/sumosim-webstart.pom
 [exec] [info]  published sumosim-webstart to /home/wolfi/.ivy2/local/net.entelijan/sumosim-webstart/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.3/jars/sumosim-webstart.jar
 [exec] [info]  published sumosim-webstart to /home/wolfi/.ivy2/local/net.entelijan/sumosim-webstart/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.3/srcs/sumosim-webstart-sources.jar
 [exec] [info]  published sumosim-webstart to /home/wolfi/.ivy2/local/net.entelijan/sumosim-webstart/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.3/docs/sumosim-webstart-javadoc.jar
 [exec] [info]  published ivy to /home/wolfi/.ivy2/local/net.entelijan/sumosim-webstart/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.3/ivys/ivy.xml
```

That is the plugin.sbt where I want to use the plugin:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    "typesave" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases",
    "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/",
    "entelijan" at "http://entelijan.net/artifactory/repo/"
)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("net.entelijan" % "sumosim-webstart" % "1.3")
```

And finally the errormessage I get

```
[exec] [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.entelijan#sumosim-webstart;1.3: not found
```

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: Your client project uses sbt 0.12.x as well?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the output of sbt publish-local.

Comment: Found additional info. When searching the repositories sbt is lookin in C:\Users\wwagner\.ivy2\local\net.entelijan\sumosim-webstart\scala_2.9.2\sbt_0.12\1.3\ivys\ivy.xml. Where does the 2.9.2 come from

Comment: The output of `publish-local` comes from the plugin project, not the client project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the Scala version that is used to build the plugin has to match the Scala version that was used to build sbt itself. Sbt 0.12 is build with Scala 2.9, sbt 0.13 with Scala 2.10.

Your plugin project uses Scala 2.10 to build the plugin. Your client project probably also uses Scala 2.10, but you use sbt 0.12 to build it. Sbt thus tries to find your plugin for Scala 2.9, which fails, since you published it for 2.10.

Comment: It helped to define the plugin projet using 2.9. Thanks. scalaVersion    := "2.9.2"

Answer (score 2):

Since the project's Scala version doesn't match the plugin when it was published, you might want to use another version of `addSbtPlugin` in `build.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.entelijan" % "sumosim-webstart" % "1.3", "0.12‌​", "2.10")
```

The second parameter is `sbtVersion` while the last is for `scalaVersion`.

Be warned that in general a plugin that doesn't match the versions as a published artefact might break with other unsupported versions of sbt and Scala.

Comment: Easiest (temp) solution.